# Where can I find online advertisers that let you place ads in rss feeds?

Tags: advertising

Looking for online advertisers like google that let you place ads in feeds?

Answer (score 3):

[Google allows ads in feeds](http://www.google.com/support/feedburner/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78956) through [feedburner](http://feedburner.google.com/) (there are a lot of feeds that use it) and advertisers access it on [AdSense](https://www.google.com/adsense).

[Yahoo](http://yahoo.com) and [Pheedo](http://pheedo.com/) also have similar setups.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [FeedBurner RSS Ads](http://www.google.com/support/feedburner/bin/answer.py?answer=86310) that Google is using to place ads in RSS.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be the publisher that advertisers will want to come and place ads in your RSS ... the above link should answer your question on how it works.

Comment: is there any other online advertisers other then FeedBurner?

Comment: A bit outdated, but has links to at least 6 rss able networks: http://www.problogger.net/archives/2006/10/21/rss-advertising-options/